# Power Series - domain of convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Determine the domain of convergence for each of the following power series:

> a) $\quad \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \cdot \frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}$
>
> b) $\quad \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k\cdot 5^{k}}$

Comment: added $\LaTeX$ check if i didn't change one of the series

Answer (score 1):

The first one is $-\sin(x)$ and for the second use the root test.
You could use for the first for sure something the root or the ratio test.

Comment: thanks i got it  its sinx/x^2

Comment: why you have $\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}$? $$\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

Comment: ∑k=1 to ∞ [−1]^k⋅x^(2k−1)]/(2k−1)!  = 1/x^2 *sinx is convergent on R \ {0} (correct me please)

Comment: @rhea i wrote the definition of sin above you atrating at 1 be careful about this

Answer (score 1):

I'm in love with D'Alembert's (ratio) Test:

$$\;\;\;\;a_n:=\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}\Longrightarrow\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\frac{(2n-1)!}{x^{2n-1}}\right|=$$

$$=\frac{|x|^2}{2n(2n+1)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Thus the first series converges absolutely for *all* $\,x\in\Bbb R\,$ .

$$b_n:=\frac{x^n}{n\,5^n}\Longrightarrow \left|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right|=\left|\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)\,5^{n+1}}\frac{n\,5^n}{x^n}\right|=|x|\frac{n}{5(n+1)}\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}\frac{|x|}{5}<1\iff$$

$$\iff |x|<5$$

Thus, the series converges absolutely for $\,-5<x<5\,$ ...and what about the extreme points $\,x=\pm 5\,$ ? Complete this.

Comment: thanks ! thats what i got but in different way :)